# Graph the polynomial $f(x)=x^4-3x^3-4x^2+3x-2$ using a graphing calculator

Tags: calculus, polynomials, graphing-functions, calculator

Graph the polynomial $f(x)=x^4-3x^3-4x^2+3x-2$ using a graphing calculator?

a) The Range
b) The Real Zeros
c) The y-intercept
d) relative minimum and Relative Maximum
e) The interval where $f(x)\le0$

Comment: I just fond the range :) with no problem it is All Real Numbers and the y-intercept of y=-2 :) please help with rest

Comment: The range is not the set of real numbers. The polynomial cannot be large negative.

Comment: _ProTip:_ only polynomials of odd degree have a range of all real numbers; polynomials of even degree will have an _absolute_ minimum (maximum) if the leading coefficient is positive (negative).

Comment: Whoever assigned you this problem is a jerk. In particular, the real zeros of this polynomial are seriously ugly and tedious to find, as are the zeroes of its derivative!

Comment: can you help me solve it :( I have been working on it for more than 20 minutes

Comment: You are supposed to use a graphing calculator to plot the curve, and read off **approximate** answers from the graph.

Comment: I give up? anyone show me how?

Comment: Did you perhaps mistype it? Aside from the $y$-intercept, there is not a single part of this problem that isn't ridiculously tedious.

Comment: @Cameron Buie The extrema are no treat either -- but the point of this may only have been to serve as a calculator exercise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y=x%5E4-3x%5E3-4x%5E2%2b3x-2), you obtain:

[image]

At the link, you'll also find a graph using a larger scale.

The point of the exercise is to "get to know" you graphing calculator: zeroing in (zoom in) to see behavior near the origin, *otherwise missing maxima, minima*, e.g., with a different scale, you might obtain the following, which doesn't look any different than a distorted parabola:

[image]

Indeed, you may need to "zoom in" to clarify the behavior even more.

And, the point of the exercise is to learn how approximate (zero in on) the key points (which graphing calculators can do): where, approximately, are there relative minima? A relative (and global) maximum? Where does it (approximately) intersect the $x-axis$ (where is y zero)?, the $y$-axis?, etc.

Note that the interval on which $f(x) < 0 \approx (-1.5163, 3.8681)$. At approximately 
$x_1 \approx -1.5163, x_2 \approx 3.8681,\;\;y = 0$.

So what's stopping you from using your graphing calculator and/or graphing technology? These are meant to *help* you! But you must be clear about what it means to be an minimum, maximum, "zero", etc.

Comment: omg that site is amazing!~

Comment: Yes it is. And so are graphing calculators. These tools all help you visualize math and understand it.

Comment: yes :D your amazing!

Comment: And the upvote goes to W|A :)

Comment: @amWhy: Answers with lovely graphics and clear explanations always get my vote! +1

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the calculator is easy to establish:
$$
   \begin{array}{c|ccccc} a & -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline \\ f(a) & 115 & 16 & -5 & -2 &-5 & -20 & -29 & 10\end{array}
$$
This suggests the minimum is close to $-29$. In fact it is $-29.4136$. For very large $|x|$, the fourth power will dominate other terms, therefore the polynomial grows boundlessly for large $|x|$. Thus the range is $(-29.4136, \infty)$.

The tabulation indicates that real zeros are in the intervals $(-2,-1)$ and $(3,4)$. In fact, using calculator (or W|A) you could establish that
$$
   x^4 -3 x^3 - 4x^2+3x-2 = \left(x-\frac{3}{4} \right)^4 - \frac{59}{8} \left(x-\frac{75}{236} \right)^2 - \frac{23737}{15104}
$$
which shows that these are the only real roots, and the polynomial is negative in between them. Approximate values of these roots are $-1.5163$ and $3.86814$

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't mistype it, then André is probably correct, and you're just supposed to approximate these things. Your graphing calculater should have tools that allow you to find approximations for the zeroes and the local extrema. You should see that the interval where $f(x)\le0$ is the closed interval with those two zeroes as endpoints. The lesser of the two local minima will be the *global* minimum of your function, so it should be clear that the range is all numbers $\ge$ the global minimum.

Comment: yes it's approximate so what is the answer?

Comment: What does your graphing calculator say the answers are?

Answer (score 0):

If your calculator is similar to a TI-84+, then perhaps this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTofCWXtYyU) will help. I haven't watched it, but the comments look good.

Comment: so  what is the inteveral where f(x) smaller then = 0